SQL counting user numbers above a certain percentage threshold of consumption
I'm trying to run this code to find the number of users in usa who made more than 10% of their phone calls in English. I think the code makes sense but I get an error when I run it. Is the problem the "Having" statement? It's a table with columns being user_id, country, call duration, number of calls
SELECT 
    count(distinct user_id),(
      SELECT (COUNT(*) 
                FROM table
                WHERE language = 'en' AND country = 'usa')/
                SELECT (COUNT(*) FROM table * 100
                ) AS Percentage
    FROM table
    HAVING percentage > 10


what dbms are you using?

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Use a derived table (i.e. a FROM clause subquery) for the aggregation. Use a case expression to do conditional aggregation.
Then count the number of users doing at least 10% of their calls in English.
SELECT count(*)
FROM (
    SELECT count(case when language = 'en' then 1 end) en_cnt, count(*) tot_cnt
    FROM table
    WHERE country = 'usa'
    GROUP BY user_id
     ) dt
WHERE en_cnt * 10 >= tot_cnt

Or:
SELECT count(*)
FROM (
    SELECT 
    FROM table
    WHERE country = 'usa'
    GROUP BY user_id
    HAVING count(case when language = 'en' then 1 end) * 10 >= count(*)
     ) dt

Note that if language is a reserved word (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SQL_reserved_words), it has to be delimited as "language".

check "estimated execution plan" If you have a huge quantity of rows

You can't reference SELECT columns in the HAVING. And you don't need the subquery, you just need two levels of aggregation
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CountEnUsMoreThan10Pct
FROM (
    SELECT
      user_id,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN language = 'en' AND country = 'usa' THEN 1 END) * 100.0 / COUNT(*) AS percentage
    FROM YourTable t
    GROUP BY user_id
) t
WHERE t.percentage > 10;

If you want all users in a separate column then you can move the WHERE clause into conditional aggregation as well.
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS countAll,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN t.percentage > 10 THEN 1 END) AS CountEnUsMoreThan10Pct
FROM (
    SELECT
      user_id,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN language = 'en' AND country = 'usa' THEN 1 END) * 100.0 / COUNT(*) AS percentage
    FROM YourTable t
    GROUP BY user_id
) t;


In case of use "COUNT(CASE WHEN language = 'en' AND country = 'usa' THEN 1 END) * 100.0 / COUNT(*) AS percentage"

SQL Server properity: "PERCENT
Optional. If PERCENT is specified, then the top rows are based on a percentage of the total result set (as specfied by the top_value). For example, TOP(10) PERCENT would return the top 10% of the full result set." ... "La rueda ya está inventada, no la intentes volver a inventar"

@AlexMuni, note the absence of a  tag.

@AlexMuni Even if that was the case I wouldn't use it as it's only relevant for TOP over the whole set.

I suggest you that you make it step by step.

number of users in usa + phone calls in english. You get user and how many calls
SELECT id_user, COUNT(id_Users_calls) FROM Users_calls WHERE language = 'en' AND country ='usa'
GROUP BY id_user

10 % of this users here



I didn't give the query solution, just the way to get it. "Don't give a bottle, teach how to find water" ;)
